# Why doesn't current flow between the wires in a coil?

Tags: electric-current

Didn't find the answer online, maybe because of bad searching. So hope you here can give me an explanation.

In an engine or transformer the coil is tightly wired, but how come the current doesn't take the shortest way through the copper wire and go sideways from the direction of the wire, but instead follow the wire all around?

Thanks in advance!
/Yacub

Comment: The wire is covered in an insulating lacquer

Comment: Thanks! Just found it has an enamel coating as you said!